# Do any banks in China offer Visa/Mastercard cards which are not credit cards?

Tags: debit-card, china

I want to have a Chinese bank account and a card that I can use for online shopping (both on Chinese sites and abroad) and I can also use outside China for ATM withdrawal and POS shopping.

Most Chinese banks seem to offer either UnionPay cards or Visa/Mastercard + UnionPay credit cards (信用卡). UnionPay is perfect in China, but I'd need a Visa/Mastercard for use abroad. However, I don't want to get a Chinese credit card, if possible (it's a bit more complicated for foreigners, plus I don't want to own an extra credit card if I don't really need one).

Do you know any Chinese banks offering that?

Answer (score 1):

No Banks in China offer Visa / master Debit Cards. They only option is to go with UnionPay which is the domestic network for debit cards / credit cards / ATM interconnection etc.

The Unionpay is expanding its interconnect network and the Credit cards are accepted at quite a few countries along with Visa/Master co-branding. However even on standalong basis UnionPay has signed agreements with quite a few countries to allow only UnionPay card to be accepted.

More details at the official site http://en.unionpay.com/comInstr/aboutUs/list_aboutUs.html

Answer (score -1):

MasterCard debit cards only need a passport from Ping An Bank. They don't offer a Visa.